# JpaRepository save value always returns null

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to post using JpaRepository and spring boot and mysql

I have a table that looks like this

```
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
| user     | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Whenever i try to save data the column user is always 0 no matter what value i pass.

My Model class looks like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cart")
public class Cart {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String id;
    @Column(name = "user")
    private Integer user;

// getters and setters
}
```

The repository looks like this

```
@Repository
public interface CartRepository extends JpaRepository<Cart, String> {

}
```

The controller looks like this

```
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/cart")
@RestController
public class CartController {

    @Autowired
    CartRepository cartRepository;



    @PostMapping(value = "/postCart")
    public String postCart(@RequestBody Cart cart){
        cartRepository.save(cart);
        return "Success";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is strange. Your id field is a String, yet in the DB its a int(11). It should be a variation of varchar. Regarding that user change it's type from int to Integer. A int cannot be null so it probably gives it the value 0.

Try also to recreate your DB model so that you are 100% sure it's matching your entity model.

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake the id should be varchar, i have edited the question